# Sqlite3 - why GLOB doesn't work with ^ $ boundaries?

Tags: sql, sqlite, glob

```
pc@pc-host:~/MyScripts/sqltest$ sqlite3 --version
3.23.1 2018-04-10 17:39:29 4bb2294022060e61de7da5c227a69ccd846ba330e31626ebcd59a94efd148b3b

pc@pc-host:~/MyScripts/sqltest$ sqlite3 sampledb.db

sqlite> .schema students
CREATE TABLE students(id integer primary key,name text,country text, thereal real, theint integer);

sqlite> select * from students;
id          name        country     thereal     theint    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Michael     usa         12.6        12        
2           John        usa         5.78        5         
3           Jack        usa         12.6        12        
4           Sara        usa         5.78        5         
5           Sally       usa         12.6        12        
6           Jena        usa         5.78        5         
7           Nancy       usa         12.6        12        
8           Adam        usa         5.78        5         
9           Stevens     usa         12.6        12
```

This doesn't work:

```
sqlite> select name,country from students where name GLOB '^[A-za-z]*a$';
```

No output...

But this does:

```
sqlite> select name,country from students where name GLOB '[A-za-z]*a';
name        country   
----------  ----------
Sara        usa       
Jena        usa
```

Why? I know that in this case is redundant to use "^$" for name, but just out of curiosity..

Comment: You tagged regex, but you're dealing with globs I believe.  The two are very different.  (And I don't think most glob systems support `^` or `$`)

Comment: there's little documentation about sqlite globs , so maybe you're right

Comment: Yeah, glob uses normal shell wildcard matching patterns.

Comment: fwiw, your redundant comment is a key point because I think the regex `^$` symbols are implied in any glob.  The regex `a` (looking for an `a` anywhere) would have to be written `*a*` using a glob system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) says:

> The GLOB operator … uses the Unix file globbing syntax for its wildcards.

And the Unix file globbing syntax does not use `^`/`$`.

GLOB always matches the entire string, so these boundary markers would not make sense.